# Ubuntu only displays on HDMI port

Tags: 13.10, asus, nvidia-optimus

I've installed ubuntu 13.10 on an Asus UX302LG with nvidia 730M.

When booted up on both liveCD and on the instalation, only the HDMI port will display the screen. Laptop screen is "on", and the system can see it, but it doesn't show anything.

What can I do to make it show the screen?

Comment: what will happen if you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 ?

Comment: I havent pressed f1 but f4 (which is the same right?)
The reslut: The external monitor goes into text mode, but the laptop screen still is only turned on, but shows nothing.